# Facebook Share Button is visually shown but doesn't fuction

Tags: facebook

I'm currently using the following code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fi_FI/sdk.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And

```
<div class="btn azm-social azm-size-64 azm-circle azm-facebook fa fa-facebook"
    data-href="https://www.facebook.com/mydomain" 
    data-layout="link">
</div>
```

This code creates the button visually but clicking it doesn't do anything. (The url is changed)

Comment: Your url is https://www.facebook.com/mydomain ? Really?

Comment: This is not enough information for someone to debug this. Do you get a Javascript error, networking error, etc?